# イニシャライズの際に指定した引数がうまく反応しません

Tags: python

以下のプログラムで質問があります。インスタンスを生成する際に、引数に「5670031」を指定しているにも関わらず、以下のエラーが出ます。

```
”NameError: name 'zipcode' is not defined”
```

Addressクラスのイニシャライザで、引数を受け取ったら、それをzipcodeとして認識するとかき、その次の関数でそれをzipcodeに指定しているのに、この様なエラーが出るのが謎です。

[追加で質問です]
print(f"住所:{address['zipcode']}{address['address1']}{address['address2']}{address['address3']}")

このコードで、なぜ「f」を書く必要があるのでしょうか？

```
import  requests
import json

#郵便番号取得
class Address:

    def __init__ (self,zipcode):
    
        self.zipcode=zipcode

    def get_address(self):
        url="https://zipcloud.ibsnet.co.jp/api/search"
        params={"zipcode":zipcode}

        res=requests.get(url,params=params)
       # print(res.text)
        
        results=response["results"]
        address=results[0]  #物によっては複数返ってくることがある
        print(f"住所:{address['zipcode']}{address['address1']}{address['address2']}{address['address3']}")  

add=Address("5670031")
result=add.get_address()

print(result)
```

Answer (score 1):

下記は特に意味のないコードですが、わかりやすさのために次のようにコードを短くしてみましょう。

```
class Address:
    def __init__ (self,zipcode):
        self.zipcode=zipcode

    def get_address(self):
        params={"zipcode":zipcode}

add=Address("5670031")
result=add.get_address()

print(result)
```

> NameError: name 'zipcode' is not defined

というエラーが出ます。では、エラーが出ないように修正してみましょう。

```
class Address:
    def __init__ (self,zipcode):
        self.zipcode=zipcode

    def get_address(self):
        params={"zipcode":self.zipcode}

add=Address("5670031")
result=add.get_address()

print(result)
```

どこが違うかお気づきになられたでしょうか。`get_address`メソッド内の `zipcode` を `self.zipcode` にかえています。プロパティにアクセスする場合は `self.` を通してアクセスしましょう。

コードの中のあちこちに同名で `zipcode` が出てきますが、スコープやPython独自の書き方のルールなどを意識して、いま自分がどの `zipcode` にアクセスしたいのかを考えてコーディングしてください。

つまり

> Addressクラスのイニシャライザで、引数を受け取ったら、それをzipcodeとして認識するとかき、その次の関数でそれをzipcodeに指定しているのに

この認識が間違いです。イニシャライザの引数 `zipcode` のスコープはイニシャライザの中だけです。**受け取った値**を他のメソッドから参照したいがために `self.zipcode=zipcode` とプロパティに代入しているのです。オブジェクト指向ははじめは慣れないと思いますが、使い方に慣れていくとよいと考えます。